# Extracting standard deviation of random effects components using glmer

Tags: r, lme4

I am using glmer and I wish to extract the standard deviation of the variance components of the random effects (intercept and slope).

I have tried using:

```
VarCorr(model)
```

which returns the two standard deviation values (plus the correlation), but I just wish to extract the Intercept and Slope SD values.

I tried using:

```
VarrCorr(model)[1]
```

to extract the random intercept SD, which lets me know that:

```
attr(,"stddev")
(Intercept)        year 
      0.075       0.011
```

but I don't know how to extract these as individual elements.

Comment: This would be much easier if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data and the code for the model that you ran (or a similar one). There are many different types of model you can run. Would `as.data.frame(VarCorr(model))` work for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this.

```
## make up a model
library(lme4)
(gm <- glmer(incidence ~ period + (size | herd),
              family = poisson, data = cbpp))
```

## Approach 1

The current version of `lme4` allows you to coerce a `VarCorr` object to a data frame:

```
as.data.frame(VarCorr(gm))
```

Then you can select rows 1:2 and column 5 to extract standard deviations of random intercept and slope.

## Approach 2

If you want to extract the values in a old-fashioned way, you can use `attributes`:

```
attributes(VarCorr(gm)$herd)$stddev
(Intercept)        size 
 1.18970662  0.08826278
```

If you want to get rid of the names (i.e., `(intercept)`, `size`), then you can use `as.numeric` or `unname`.

Comment: I don't think you need `as.numeric()` in your second approach.

Comment: You are right. I assumed the PO wanted to remove the names but he may not.

Comment: if you want to remove names then I would use `unname()` -- seems more explicit.