# Extracting results from a `lmermod` object

Tags: r, lme4

I would like to extract some results from a `lmerMod` object

```
require(lme4)
(fm1 <- lmer(Yield ~ 1|Batch, Dyestuff))
```

This produces

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Yield ~ 1 | Batch
   Data: Dyestuff
REML criterion at convergence: 319.6543
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 Batch    (Intercept) 42.00   
 Residual             49.51   
Number of obs: 30, groups:  Batch, 6
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)  
       1527
```

In particular, I would like to extract the standard deviations of the 2 random effects, i.e. 42.00 and 49.51. I guess there may be a built-in method to do this, but I couldn't find it quickly so I thought I should be able to find it by using `str(fm1)`, which produces this:

```
Formal class 'lmerMod' [package "lme4"] with 13 slots
  ..@ resp   :Reference class 'lmerResp' [package "lme4"] with 9 fields
  .. ..$ Ptr    :<externalptr> 
  .. ..$ mu     : num [1:30] 1510 1510 1510 1510 1510 ...
  .. ..$ offset : num [1:30] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..$ sqrtXwt: num [1:30] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ sqrtrwt: num [1:30] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ weights: num [1:30] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ wtres  : num [1:30] 35.1 -69.9 -69.9 10.1 70.1 ...
  .. ..$ y      : num [1:30] 1545 1440 1440 1520 1580 ...
  .. ..$ REML   : int 1
  .. ..and 26 methods, of which 14 are possibly relevant:
  .. ..  allInfo, copy#envRefClass, initialize, initialize#lmResp,
  .. ..  initializePtr, initializePtr#lmResp, objective, ptr, ptr#lmResp,
  .. ..  setOffset, setResp, setWeights, updateMu, wrss
  ..@ Gp     : int [1:2] 0 6
  ..@ call   : language lmer(formula = Yield ~ 1 | Batch, data = Dyestuff)
  ..@ frame  :'data.frame':     30 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Yield: num [1:30] 1545 1440 1440 1520 1580 ...
  .. ..$ Batch: Factor w/ 6 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula' length 3 Yield ~ 1 + Batch
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Yield, Batch)
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Yield" "Batch"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Batch"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "Batch"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Yield, Batch)
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "numeric" "factor"
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Yield" "Batch"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars.fixed")= language list(Yield)
  .. ..- attr(*, "formula")=Class 'formula' length 3 Yield ~ 1 | Batch
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  ..@ flist  :List of 1
  .. ..$ Batch: Factor w/ 6 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int 1
  ..@ cnms   :List of 1
  .. ..$ Batch: chr "(Intercept)"
  ..@ lower  : num 0
  ..@ theta  : num 0.848
  ..@ beta   : num 1527
  ..@ u      : num [1:6] -20.755 0.461 33.669 -27.212 66.877 ...
  ..@ devcomp:List of 2
  .. ..$ cmp : Named num [1:10] 9.15 1.88 61495.41 9590.84 71086.25 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "ldL2" "ldRX2" "wrss" "ussq" ...
  .. ..$ dims: Named int [1:12] 30 30 1 29 1 6 1 1 0 1 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:12] "N" "n" "p" "nmp" ...
  ..@ pp     :Reference class 'merPredD' [package "lme4"] with 18 fields
  .. ..$ Lambdat:Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:6] 0 1 2 3 4 5
  .. .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:7] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
  .. .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 6 6
  .. .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. ..@ x       : num [1:6] 0.848 0.848 0.848 0.848 0.848 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  .. ..$ LamtUt :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:30] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:31] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 6 30
  .. .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. ..@ x       : num [1:30] 0.848 0.848 0.848 0.848 0.848 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  .. ..$ Lind   : int [1:6] 1 1 1 1 1 1
  .. ..$ Ptr    :<externalptr> 
  .. ..$ RZX    : num [1:6, 1] 1.98 1.98 1.98 1.98 1.98 ...
  .. ..$ Ut     :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:30] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:31] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 6 30
  .. .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. ..@ x       : num [1:30] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  .. ..$ Utr    : num [1:6] 6384 6481 6634 6354 6787 ...
  .. ..$ V      : num [1:30, 1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ VtV    : num [1, 1] 30
  .. ..$ Vtr    : num 45825
  .. ..$ X      : num [1:30, 1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:30] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "(Intercept)"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int 0
  .. ..$ Xwts   : num [1:30] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ Zt     :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:30] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:31] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 6 30
  .. .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. ..@ x       : num [1:30] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  .. ..$ beta0  : num 0
  .. ..$ delb   : num 1527
  .. ..$ delu   : num [1:6] -20.755 0.461 33.669 -27.212 66.877 ...
  .. ..$ theta  : num 0.848
  .. ..$ u0     : num [1:6] 0 0 0 0 0 0
  .. ..and 42 methods, of which 30 are possibly relevant:
  .. ..  b, beta, CcNumer, copy#envRefClass, initialize, initializePtr,
  .. ..  installPars, L, ldL2, ldRX2, linPred, P, ptr, RX, RXdiag, RXi,
  .. ..  setBeta0, setDelb, setDelu, setTheta, solve, solveU, sqrL, u, unsc,
  .. ..  updateDecomp, updateL, updateLamtUt, updateRes, updateXwts
  ..@ optinfo:List of 7
  .. ..$ optimizer: chr "bobyqa"
  .. ..$ control  :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ iprint: int 0
  .. ..$ derivs   :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ gradient: num 1.61e-07
  .. .. ..$ Hessian : num [1, 1] 14.1
  .. ..$ conv     :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ opt : int 0
  .. .. ..$ lme4: list()
  .. ..$ feval    : int 16
  .. ..$ warnings : list()
  .. ..$ val      : num 0.848
```

...but this leaves me none the wiser.

Comment: Have you tried using `attributes(fm1)`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I had not, so I just tried and found the 2nd item as `fm1@devcomp$cmp[10]` but I still can't find the first one

Comment: The class is spelled `lmerMod`

Comment: closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084924/extracting-standard-deviation-of-random-effects-components-using-glmer/25085736#25085736

Comment: `attr(summary(fm1)$varcor, "sc")`, `attr(summary(fm1)$varcor$Batch, "stddev")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lme4 supplies `VarCorr` for extracting variance and correlation components:

```
varcor <- VarCorr(fm1)
as.data.frame(varcor)
#       grp        var1 var2    vcov   sdcor
#1    Batch (Intercept) <NA> 1764.05 42.0006
#2 Residual        <NA> <NA> 2451.25 49.5101
```

Comment: if the OP can suggest where in the documentation he looked/was expecting to find this info, I could try to improve the docs so this would be easier to find ...

Comment: Well. I just looked (in sequence) at `?lmer` and after looking in the Index at `?'lmerMod-class'` and tried `?summary.lmerMod` (although that last one doesn't exist.) I also considered `vcov` but didn't go there since the context indicated that was only for fixed effects. Seems that I probably should have gone there since some helpful annotater might in the future put a link there as well.

Comment: I think the inconvenient thing is that `class(fm1)` is `lmerMod`, but the methods you want are for class `VarCorr.merMod.` When you do `methods(class="lm")`, you get a bunch of useful functions, but `methods(class="lmerMod")` returns nothing. Unless the user is aware of the `VarCorr` function (by reading the documentation) or has extracted `summary(fm1)$varcor` after looking through the `str`, it can be difficult for a user to find the info they want. When I ran into this issue earlier last year, I used the super ghetto `capture.output` into text processing method. edited to reflect `lmerMod`

Comment: @BenBolker: When one goes to stats::vcov (from the link at lme4::merMod-class , it appeared the 'merMod' classes were not mentioned even though an extensive list of other classes were. Maybe an update to that page is also warranted.

Comment: @Vlo try `methods(class='merMod')` although I'm not sure how the naive user (such as myself) without this discussion would have been able to know that lmerMod's were a subset of merMod's.

Comment: `merMod` does the trick. I don't know much about R package writing, but I find it confusing that the output of `lmer` is not `merMod` class.

Comment: That does the job, thanks, but nevertheless what an absolute pain in the ass to extract just one value!